# Asprise scanner.js function myCallBackFunc error

Tags: javascript

In my application I'm Using Asprise scanner.js. By clicking a Simple Scan button there was a successful connection with my scanner device "HP 5590", then a complete document scanning. But there was an error show up rather than the scanned image. the error is :
"Callback function invoked: success = false, mesg = User cancelled. Thumbs: 0, images: 0 "

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Note: my OS is Windows Vista.
      Firefox and IE show the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using windows 7 rather than windows vista.

Asprise scanner.js shows error on windows vista.